# Angular: custom pipe for change text

Tags: angular, pipe

I have a function that Random a number between 1 and 20.

The task I want to perform: **When an elevator is in a lobby, use a custom pipe to display the word lobby instead of the number 1.**

func in the service:

```
getNumbersInfinite(){
    return interval(1000).pipe(map(()=> Math.floor(Math.random() * 20) + 1));
  }
```

in the component:

```
floor?: Observable<Number>;
  constructor(private randomNumberGen: RandomNumberGeneratorService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.floor = this.randomNumberGen.getNumbersInfinite();
  }
```

html:

```
<div class="elevator">
<pre class="floor">{{this.floor | async}}</pre>
</div>
```

Comment: Please create a working example on https://stackblitz.com/

Comment: I do not succeed, I have to through GitHub?
@GetOffMyLawn

Comment: You need to copy the relevant code to stackblitz to create a working example we can work with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, create the pipe `replaceWordLoby.pipe.ts` [DOC](https://angular.io/guide/pipes#transforming-data-using-pipes)

```
@Pipe({
    name: "replaceWordLoby",
})
export class ReplaceWordLobyPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(value: Number, ...args: unknown[]): string {
        // return word lobby 
    }
}
```

then import the class into the `declarations` array in `your.module.ts` file

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [ReplaceWordLobyPipe],
})
export class YourModule {}
```

Now you can use it like:

```
<p>
  {{ floor | async | replaceWordLoby }}
</p>
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-xp8vrm)

Comment: its not good because **replaceWordLoby** return number and floor return **obserable<Number>**

Comment: you using the `async` pipe which is returning the `Number` only not `obserable<Number>`. after that send the value in `replaceWordLoby` pipe. now change  the `transform` method body as per your need and return the string value

Comment: but i got this error: **Argument of type 'Number | null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Observable<Number>'.
  Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'Observable<Number>'.ngtsc(2345)**

Comment: i return the word "lobby" in pipe

Comment: but without your code is not null so how?

Comment: can you share the actual method body of `getNumbersInfinite()`?

Comment: This I uploaded all my code here in the post

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245274/discussion-between-empty-brain-and-yosef-abada).